Replacing blower on furnace and it’s filled with water
My blower was failing on my old furnace and I am replacing it. It sounded like there was water sloshing around inside it but I assumed it was just the bearings wearing out and that I didn’t know what that sounded like. But when I got it off there was a substantial amount of water inside (at least half a cup). I assume this should not be the case. Is there anything I need to do so this doesn’t happen to the new one?

It’s a Lennox Elite Series and the blower connects to power, ground, the air in and out, and a rubber hose that I surmise may be for condensation.
This is the hose disconnected from the blower

This is the thing the hose (left) connects to on the other end.


From the looks of it, the device that the hose connects to is an air-pressure switch. It is usually used to detect that a fan actually creates an airflow when it is running.

That looks like a draft inducer.

I had a very similar problem a few weeks ago—furnace wouldn't run.  There was water sloshing in the collector box (some kind of air manifold).  Draining water out of the box through one of the hoses (going between it and the pressure switch) solved the problem and made the furnace run.  However, later it happened again.  Turned out the trap on the side of the furnace had gunked up—not solid, but that kind of almost-set jello texture that happens when water sits for a while.  The gunk was preventing water from freely draining through the trap, keeping it in the collector box.  Pulling off the trap and cleaning out the gunk solved the problem.  You'll have to figure out where your trap is based on your specific model, and hopefully your problem matches mine.

This was the essential problem in my case too. Thanks!

@Charles excellent!

You need to determine where the water's coming from. Make sure the hose for the condensation isn't clogged and connected to the pan and draining correctly. If you have a humidifier, make sure the supply isn't leaking. Monitor it for a while to make sure you solved the problem.

I was thinking that I might blow air into the hose and see if that helps?

@Charles  Those hoses do get clogged. I have to clean mine out every two years.

Is blowing air (from a compressor) an ok way to do this?

@Charles  My hose/pipe is 10 feet long so I have to hook it up to a water faucet and blow it out.  Air from a compressor might only partially open it up.
